# Inverstion matrix as parallel transport in CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory

In [Gauge/Gravity Duality by Ammon and Erdmenger](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/gaugegravity-duality/16CCA2E431B24AEF1B51B0F9C5BE755E) (pg. 105), and [CFT Lecture Notes by Osborn](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/CFTNotes.pdf) (pg. 4), it is stated that the interval between two points $x$ and $y$ transforms under general conformal transformation as:

$$
(x' - y')^2 = \frac{(x - y)^2}{\Omega(x) \Omega(y)}
$$

Where $\Omega(x)$ is a point-by-point scaling factor from:

$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x) \rightarrow \Omega(x)^{-2} g_{\mu\nu}(x)
$$

The derivation by Osborn works by squaring and integrating the infinitesimal version of the transformation of the interval:

$$
\delta (x - y)^\mu = \frac{1}{2} \left(o(x) + o(y)\right) (x - y)^\mu + O(\omega)
$$

(See [video lecture](https://youtu.be/mqBLs1Ype4Q?si=_5gr8B0hzi4uXTug&t=642), for example)

However, this doesn't seem to make much sense since $x$ and $y$ are different points on the manifold (not necessarily close to each other), and $x - y$ is technically not a vector and thus cannot be fed into the metric tensor and squared. Why can this formula by applied here?

Confusingly Ammon/Erdemenger view the interval transformation law as a consequence of the inversiton matrix taking a "role of a parallel transport" without any further elaboration. Why is this the case?